# How to create a list of numbers 1-1000 to simplify?

Tags: list, python-2.7, math, reddit

I am working on a "Whats my number?" program (http://goo.gl/upgkZ2) as posted on reddit and I was wondering if there was a way I could have a list of numbers 1-1000 and remove groups of numbers that follow a certain criteria. I was wondering if there was any simpler way to do this?

Comment: Please make sure to post *relevant* code inline in the question. If you link is just spam - it may be safer to remove post yourself.

Comment: Note: the challenge you're attempting is wrong. There are multiple numbers that satisfy the conditions of the challenge.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a list of 1-1000 in a simpler way by using:

```
tons = list(xrange(1000))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a list at all to solve this problem (well, find the two solutions to this problem). Loop over the numbers and `continue` (return to the top of the loop for the next iteration) for each condition that fails to be met:

```
for i in xrange(10,1001):
    s_i = str(i)
    if '1' in s_i or '7' in s_i:
        continue
    if sum([int(d) for d in s_i]) > 10:
        continue
    ...
    print i, 'satisfies the conditions.'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use filter on the initial list removing each case one at a time
For efficiency, cut out the biggest ones first, like the last case removes 90% of the list

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy to create an array:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.arange(1,1001)
```